# How to obtain path from ZipFile objects that could be passed into OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, python-zipfile

I would like to pass the image file into OpenCV to create a NumPy array  without unzipping it.

My code looks like this:

```
zip_file = r'D:\Folder\small_img.zip'

with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file) as zip:
    for info in zip.infolist():
        path_to_image = os.path.abspath(info.filename)
        zip_img = zip.open(info.filename)
        pil_img = Image.open(zip_img).convert('RGB')
        # cv_img = cv.imread(*)
```

The place where I put a `*` is what I'm not sure what to pass in. I have created a few variables of class Pillow `Image` (`pil_img`), and `ZipFileExt` (`zip_img`). I understand that `cv2.imread` only accepts a path. So, I have tried to pass in a path name, however I have not de-zipped the zip file, hence I also tried to create a absolute path (`path_to_image`) that looks like (`'D:\Folder\File1.jpg'`), and a file name (`info.filename`) that looks like (`File1.jpg`).

However, most of them render an error message:

```
TypeError: Can't convert object of type 'Image' to 'str' for 'filename'
```

or

```
TypeError: Can't convert object of type 'ZipExtFile' to 'str' for 'filename'
```

Or, in the case where I pass in `path_to_image` or `info.filename`, it returns `None`.

Anyone knows what I could pass into `cv2.imread` to get the NumPy array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [`cv2.imdecode`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga26a67788faa58ade337f8d28ba0eb19e) for that purpose:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile('images.zip') as zf:
    for info in zf.infolist():
        zip_img = zf.open(info.filename)
        cv_img = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(zip_img.read(), dtype=np.uint8),
                              cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

On the `ZipExtFile` object obtained from [`zipfile.ZipFile.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open), you can call [`read`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase.read) to get the raw bytes. You then need [`np.frombuffer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) to get a proper input for `cv2.imdecode`.

If you (also) need the Pillow `Image` object, you could also simply cast that one to some NumPy array, but have to keep in mind to correct the ordering from RGB (Pillow) to BGR (OpenCV):

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile('images.zip') as zf:
    for info in zf.infolist():
        zip_img = zf.open(info.filename)
        pil_img = Image.open(zip_img)
        cv_img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(pil_img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
```

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
NumPy:         1.20.2
OpenCV:        4.5.1
Pillow:        8.2.0
----------------------------------------
```